# Menu to toggle between two different actions onClick in Android

Tags: android, button, menu, toggle

I am trying to make a menu icon respond to two different actions on first click should trigger the first action on second click of the same menu trigger another action, when clicked again it should call the first action just like toggling between actions

The method

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int _clicks = 0;
    int count;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_sort:
            count = ++_clicks;
            if (count == 1){
                Cursor cursor2 = databaseManager.queryAllInsects(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME +  " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
                mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor2);
                return true;
            } if (count == 2){
                Cursor cursor3 = databaseManager.queryAllInsects(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_DANGERLEVEL +  " COLLATE NOCASE DESC");
                mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor3);
                return true;
            }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I actually did this but once it get to the second click, it doesn't toggle back to the first function i.e not clickable again. Can any one help ou. I most stick with the action bar menu

Comment: if you want to maintain sequence 1,2,1,2 just set  _clicks =0 in if (count == 2) and make _clicks as class variable also here you can manage it with one variable too

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a `boolean` instead?

```
boolean b = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(b) {
        // Do one thing.
    }
    else {
        // Do another.
    }
    // Invert the state of the boolean. (This will enter the other case next time.)
    b = !b;
}
```

If you'd prefer to use an integer, you could try the `modulo` operator. By dividing the number by two, the remainder could be used for indicating whether the number was odd or even. Then you could write the sequence as follows:

```
int x = 0;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(((x++) % 2) == 0) { // Is the remainder equal to 0? (Even or Odd)
        // Do one thing.
    }
    else  {
       // Do another.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int _clicks = 0;
int count;

switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_sort:
        count = ++_clicks;
        if (count == 1){
            Cursor cursor2 = databaseManager.queryAllInsects(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME +  " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
            mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor2);
            return true;
        } if (count == 2){
            _clicks = 0;
            Cursor cursor3 = databaseManager.queryAllInsects(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_DANGERLEVEL +  " COLLATE NOCASE DESC");
            mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor3);
            return true;
        }

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

This way, by the second click, the variable _click will have a value = 0, then, by the third click, the first action will be shown.